# ASP VB. NET Highlight Row to Red color

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ping

I would like to select the row and highlight to Red if status equal to Offline.

How can i do it in ASP .NET?

I saw quite alot of example talking about protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e).

I should create the class in Controller? or View? Very confuse on the new MVC >_<

Please help

Comment: asp.net web forms or asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the method CSS TD Class to red, but i could not get it work. Any idea?

My code as follow:-

```
    @For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    Dim status = Html.Action("showPing", New With {.ipaddress = currentItem.IP})
    If status.Equals("Online") Then
        @<tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.IP)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Action("showPing", New With {.ipaddress = currentItem.IP})
            </td>
        </tr> 
    Else
        @<tr>
            <td class="red">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="red">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.IP)
            </td>
            <td class="red">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Location)
            </td>
            <td class="red">
                @Html.Action("showPing", New With {.ipaddress = currentItem.IP})
            </td>
        </tr> 
    End If
```

Next

It showed all red. I am using ASP .NET VB MVC4

Comment: Changes to Dim status As String = Html.Action("showPing", New With {.ipaddress = currentItem.IP}).ToString and it is working fine now! THank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

You should just reference the row values `Online/Offline status` from the `model` and change the `CSS` accordingly to highlight the row.  Since no code has been provided I have mocked an example up:

I.e.

```
public class OnlineOfflineElements {
    public List<Element> elements { get; set; }

} 

public class Element {
   public bool isOnline { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `View`:

```
@foreach (var status in elements) {
   if (status.isOnline) {
      <tr class="Online">
   } else { 
      <tr class="Offline">
   }
    // Other model content here
}
```

Comment: I tried the method CSS TD Class to red, but i could get it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have just been able to complete this for a gridview in my webpage. I needed to be able to change a row of data when offline to red.

```
    Protected Sub grdName_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdName.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Status").ToString() = "OffLine" Then
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Betty